# What is an example of O(2^(n/2))?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o, discrete-mathematics

Is it really any different from O(2^n)??

It's like saying n where n is in the set of i/2 where i is any real number. If i is a set of real numbers, then n would be so as well and so O(2^n) is the same as O(2^(n/2)) right?

Comment: 1)  One would be to compute 2^(n/2) by incrementing a counter :-). 2) No it isn't.  Consider that 2^N == 2^(N/2) * 2^(N/2)

Comment: Would you say that `O(3^n)` is the same as `O(2^n)`? What about `O(sqrt(2)^n)`?

Comment: Also, questions about computational complexity and asymptotics are usually better answered on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Your explanation is pretty confuse. And wrong.

Answer (score 3):

2^(n/2) = √(2^n); also, lim 2^(n/2)/2^n = 0, so these two orders of complexity are quite different. In fact, they are much more different than n vs. n².

---

An example of O(2^n) cost is counting the ordered partitions of n+1 (e.g. n=3 -> (1,1,1,1), (2,1,1), (1,2,1), (1,1,2), (2,2), (3,1), (1,3), (4) -> 8).

An example of O(2^(n/2)) cost is counting the ordered partitions of n+1 that are symmetric (e.g. n=3 -> (1,1,1,1), (1,2,1), (2,2), (4) -> 4).

Comment: Not sure that I agree with "much more different".  In practice `O(2^n)` might be doable for `n=30`, `O(2^(n/2))` might be doable for `n=60`, `O(n^2` might be doable for `n=30_000`, and `O(n)` might be doable for `n=1_000_000_000`.  So sure, the ratio of growth rates for the first 2 is larger.  But the ratio of what is doable is larger for the second 2.

Comment: In theory, no.  Because it all depends on the constants.  But in practice it really does tend to work out that way. And the reason why people care about the theory in practice is because of how it usually works out in practice.

Comment: Huh?  All that I'm saying is that people mostly care about the difference between `O(n)` and `O(n^2)` not because of the nice theory (though I do like the theory), but because in practice `O(n)` algorithms do run faster on real data sets.  How did you get from there to saying all algorithms run in one second and asymptotic analysis is for dummies?

Answer (score -1):

**O(2^n)** and **O(2^(n/2))** are similar, but not identical: **O(2^n)** represents an algorithm whose time complexity is directly proportional to **2^n**, while **O(2^(n/2))** represents an algorithm whose time complexity is directly proportional to **2^(n/2)**. This means that **O(2^n)** represents a problem that will double in size with each additional input, while **O(2^(n/2))** represents a problem that will increase by a factor of **2^(1/2)** with each additional input.

These complexities can be quite different in terms of the actual running time of the algorithm. For example, a problem of (relative) size 8 with **O(2^n)** is going to take `2^8 = 256` times more computation than the same problem with (relative) size 1, while **O(2^(n/2))** will take `2^(8/2) = 16` times more computation. While both complexities are exponential, the actual running time can be very different.

In general, **O(2^n)** is considered to be much worse than **O(2^(n/2))**, as it increases much faster. So, it's important to understand the difference between these complexities, and not confuse them with each other.

Comment: First paragraph is just the definition of big O notation, so kinda useless here. Second paragraph has some wrong math.

Comment: @AloisChristen: first paragraph is not particularly helpful, granted -- but the second and third paragraph raise a valid point, IMNSHO...

Comment: @ChristianSeverin agree that third paragraph is a valid point, and it would make a nice starting point. But the second paragraph is just wrong : `2^8` is not 256 times more that `2^4`. Being wrong when showing how those complexity differs is a pretty big deal for me.

Comment: @AloisChristen: ah, I see what you mean. My guess is that they simply mistyped and meant to compare a size-8 problem with a size-1 problem. (editing)